# Cython: UserWarning: Unknown Extension options: 'include_path'

Tags: python-2.7, cython

I have a Cython module that I inherited. I built it once. Then when I go to build it a second time I get the following error:

```
mhoggan@mhoggan-C02S81PRG8WM:pcl_functions (master=)$ sudo python setup.py build_ext --inplace
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/extension.py:133: UserWarning: Unknown Extension options: 'include_path'
  warnings.warn(msg)
```

What could be the cause? I am new to Cython and it does not make since why the module would build once, then subsequently give me this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you've used a different version of Cython the last time. Check version with `cython --version`.

The cythonize() function seems to accept include_path: https://github.com/cython/cython/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=include_path

Are you using Extension or cythonize? For cythonize usage see https://github.com/cython/cython/wiki/enhancements-distutils_preprocessing

Extension() accepts "include_dirs" option:
https://github.com/cztomczak/cefpython/blob/f8286e0ff5abf32242986aca2e7bb8fd3f6a60ff/src/linux/setup/setup.py#L66